# Complete code for adding an OnClickListener to a Preference

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

Ok I swear this is the last time I will ask this question. I've tried a trillion different solutions and non of them work.

First here is the blank Settings activity as created by Android Studio:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.settings, new SettingsFragment())
            .commit();


    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }


public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);
    }
  }

}
```

And here is my preferences xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <Preference
        android:id="@+id/resetSettings"
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="reset_settings"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:summary="@string/reset_description"
        android:title="@string/reset_title" />
    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="switch_preference"
        android:summary="Instead of values from 0 to 255, the seekBar will use percentages"
        android:title="Use Percentages" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

I want an OnClickListener attached to the Reset preference so it can open an Alert Dialog that asks the user if they want to delete all app data.

Answer (score 0):

In settings fragment in onCreatePreference add:

```
Preference 
resetPreference=findPreference("your Preference key");
```

Then for the click listener add:

```
resetPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListenere(new 
Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

@overide
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) 
 {
       //your code goes here
       return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: that function needs to be used inside SettingsFragment which is a static class that can't use non-static methods

Comment: There is no need for  settings fragment to be static since it is not an inner class

Comment: Wait, this website has somehow messed up the code I copy/pasted

Comment: fixed it. Very sorry.

Comment: SettingsFragment is a static inner class. This is how Android Studio makes it.